# Check for character between brackets using Regex

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find a method that will return me a certain character if it's found between two other characters.

More specifically, the problem I'm currently trying to solve is:
Let's say I have this String "((A+B)-(C+D))". I am trying to find a RegEx that can allow me to capture ONLY the two '('s, "(**(**A+B)-**(**C+D))".

I am trying to use the look-behind and look-ahead constructs, but so far I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Also, I haven't been able to find a guide on the use of the asterisk inside the look-around constructs, since I presume it doesn't serve its usual function (or at least not exactly). Can someone tell me or point me to where I can learn more about this?

Comment: For your sample input you can find the opening `(` that are left besides a word-character by use of a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1539/word-boundary#t=201707312028454631139) to the right. Demo: [`\(\b`](https://regex101.com/r/k5kiVx/1/)

Comment: It is really helpful to know the regex environment you are using.